# RSS feed warns about PHP's DATE_RFC822 year representation not being four digits long

Tags: php, date, rss, rfc822

I'm creating a RSS feed with PHP and I set the date using PHP's build in `DATE_RFC822` format:

```
<lastBuildDate>' . date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime($posts['date'])) . '</lastBuildDate>
```

Which results in this:

```
<lastBuildDate>Tue, 01 Oct 13 10:10:00 +0200</lastBuildDate>
```

When I now try to validate it, it passes, but with the following recommendation:

> Problematical RFC 822 date-time value: Tue, 01 Oct 13 10:10:00 +0200

Which has some further information on this page: [Problematical RFC 822 date-time value](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/ProblematicalRFC822Date.html):

> The value specified must meet the Date and Time specifications as defined by RFC822, with the exception that the year SHOULD be expressed as four digits.

How can I update the year to a four digit value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There also exists the `DATE_RSS` constant: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rss which is of the expected format:

```
D, d M Y H:i:s O
```

So just use `date(DATE_RSS, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was an easy one.

Answer (score 2):

Use DATE_RSS instead that contains it exactly